# Find the last visible textbox index number

Tags: jquery

I want to find the last visible textbox index number with jquery, 
I have tried the code below but giving wrong index number :

```
var lastIndex = $('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:last').index();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will probably be caused by the fact `index()` is looking at siblings. You're selector is working fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/2ueea/.

Try the following:

`$('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:last').index('input[type=text]');`

You'll get the index of the input in relation to the other inputs on that page. If that's not what you want to receive, tell us.

Comment: could you tell me, if last input type can either be a textbox or dropdownlist or text area, then how the code would look like ???

Comment: Try this: `$('input[type=text],select,textarea').filter(':visible:last').index('input[type=text],select,textarea');`

Comment: Hi this filtering does not work after Jquery Datatable .... any thought on that issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('form').find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:last').index();
```

Comment: You are missing ' after input[type=text]

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form input[type='text']").filter(":visible:last").index();
```

It is split up with `filter()` so the first selector can be passed directory to [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

If it's not an issue, just place the entire selector as one string.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
   var textboxIndex = $('input[type=text]').filter(':visible').length -1;
```